# making a python object unsable after a finalize-type call

Tags: python, object, resources, destructor

I have a python object which wraps a sensitive and important resource on the system. I have a `cleanup()` function which safely releases various locks used by the object.

I want to make sure that after a call to `cleanup()` the object becomes unusable. Ideally, any call to any member function of the object would raises an exception. Is there a way to do this that does not involve checking a flag in every function?

Comment: Are you using this in the context of a `with` statement?  Are you using the context manager protocol?

Comment: just spent some time figuring out whether i will have at least python 2.5 on all the systems that run this code, and it looks like i can't really count on that. too bad -- this is exactly the right way to make sure i don't have stray references laying around.

Comment: "can't really count on that"?  Why not?  Make it a requirement.  What's wrong with requiring Python 2.6?

Comment: Alas, one of the major linux server distros (RHEL 5 / CentOS 5) still ships with Python 2.4. It's very hard to upgrade python on those systems, and they're part of the environment mix I'm writing the software for.

Comment: "Very Hard"?  We do it regularly.  What makes it "very hard"?  Am I missing some hidden complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to simply set all the instance variables to `None`.  Then, doing pretty much anything will cause AttributeError or TypeError.  A more sophisticated approach is to wrap instance methods with a decorator.  The decorator can check if the close has been disposed.  If so, it throws an exception:

```
class Unusable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.alive = True

    def notcleanedup(func):
        def operation(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.alive:
                func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise Exception("Use after cleanup")

        return operation

    @notcleanedup
    def sensitive(self, a, b):
        print a, b

    def cleanup(self):
        self.alive = False
```